# Architecture Patterns around Angular2: Redux, Flux, React, Reactive, RxJS, Ngrx, MVI,

Tags: reactjs, angular, redux, rxjs, ngrx

All the names of these libraries/frameworks begin with the letter R/N or sound very similar; irritations are guaranteed:

**react/redux | flux | ngrx | @ngrx/store | RxJS/ReactiveX | MVI | ....**

**Can anyone see through this madness?** **I am trying to clarify, please help me, if I'am wrong:**

**[Redux](http://redux.js.org/)** is a "predictable state container" for JavaScript apps and a lightweight  implementation of **[Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)**. Can I say: It is the standard implementation of flux for Angular2? (But there are also great [lerning videos about redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) without Angular2.)

**[Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)** is the application architecture that Facebook uses for building client-side web applications. It complements **[React's](https://facebook.github.io/react/)** (ReactJS) composable view components by utilizing a unidirectional data flow. But flux is only a pattern, not an implementation.

**[React](https://facebook.github.io/react/)** (ReactJS) is the main competitor of [**Angular2** (angular.io)](https://angular.io/), although it is rather a big library than a framework.

[**Reactive Extensions for JavaScript (RxJS)**](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) is a reactive streams library that allows you to work with asynchronous data streams. It pursues the objectives of the [**Reactive-Manifesto.**](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/)

Angular2 has it's own Reactive Extensions and they are called as [**Ngrx - Reactive Extensions for Angular2.**](https://github.com/ngrx)

Then there is something like **[@ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store)**, which is RxJS powered state management inspired by Redux for Angular 2 apps. Oops-a-daisy!

As an alternative to Flux, [André Staltz](https://twitter.com/andrestaltz) has presented the unidirectional [**Model-View-Intent (MVI) architecture**](http://futurice.com/blog/reactive-mvc-and-the-virtual-dom), based on RxJS Observables, which he uses as the basis for [**Cycle.js**](http://cycle.js.org/). Whilst Angular 2 does have a form of two-way data binding, it does not prescribe a data flow architecture. One of it's selling features is being pattern agnostic and that it will work with an MVC or a Flux architecture. Therefore it's up to as developers to choose an appropriate pattern. [>> Source](http://blog.lambda-it.ch/reactive-data-flow-in-angular-2/)

Comment: Not too broad, nearly all of them are architectur patterns around angular2, don't get confused because of the comparison between react and angular below,..

Comment: React: A declarative framework for building UI. Key features is Virtual DOM. 

Flux: App architecture for React. It is not a framework.
The main idea is to simplify the architecture of spa app mitigating issue related to MVC pattern MV* specially in relation with the update of the models.

Redux: App architecture inspired by Flux, main biggest difference is that it uses a single store which contains all the state for your app.

RxJS: Library dedicated to the observer pattern.
It facilitate orchestrating asynchronous and event-based computations.

MVI and MVC:
Architectural patterns.

Answer (score 5):

### React vs Angular

**React** is just a library to render the view - nothing more, while **Angular** is whole platform. Although it may seem they are targeting different problems, usually they're both choice to make while working on webapps.

Why is that? Because more often you think about React as React + whole ecosystem (router, forms libraries, state management etc.).

### Flux and Redux

You can see that **Flux/Redux** is often associated with React but that's not exactly true. **Flux** and **Redux** are just an idea of application-state management. However **Redux** (which is the most popular now) has it's own implementation which now is a one of React official libraries. There are also [other flux implementations](https://github.com/voronianski/flux-comparison).

### Reactive programming

It's a paradigm. I strongly encourage you to go through [this](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754). It's long but it's worth it.

### RxJS and @ngrx

Angular uses streams internally in core e.g. to manage change detection. Again streams are just the idea while **RxJS** is one of the implementations of that idea. **@ngrx** is a set of helpers built on the top of RxJS. One of them is Redux-inspired implementation of state management called [@ngrx/store](http://@ngrx/store).

### MVI

It's an architectural pattern (like MVC) to structure apps pushed by [Cycle.js](http://cycle.js.org/model-view-intent.html). Here is a great explanation of [Unidirectional UI Architectures](http://staltz.com/unidirectional-user-interface-architectures.html) we're talking about by André Staltz - creator of **Cycle.js**.

Comment: Redux is not "official" anything.  It's just been moved into an organization called "ReactJS", which is simply a group of devs that is trying to maintain some commonly used libraries with a community approach.  It's not owned by Facebook in any way.  That said, yes, it is heavily associated with the React developer community in general.